# How to compute the number of occurencies of elements in a list using list comprehensions in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, counting

Given a list like this one

`arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`

I would like to compute the number of occurencies of each element and storing it in a new list but using a list comprehension like this:

```
occ = [arr.count(e) for e in arr]
```

but this prints out the original `array: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`
instead of `[2, 3, 2]` which are respectively the number of occurences of 1, 2, and 3 in the input arry.

Why is that happening and how to fix it ?

N.B: it is mandatory to use a list comprehension if possible.

Comment: I get `occ == [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason is tht when you do

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

and arr.count(1) , you'll get the number of occurencies of the number 1 in the list arr.
And then when you do

```
occ = [arr.count(e) for e in arr]
```

you are actually computing arr.count(1) 2 times, then arr.count(3) three times, and then arr.count(3) two times.

So, what you have to do in order to not repeat the numbers is count the unique numbers in the list, which are just 1, 2, and 3.
So the right code would be:

```
occ = [arr.count(e) for e in set(arr)]
```

and now when you print the list, you'll get [2,3,2] as expected.

Comment: He wants ```[2, 3, 2]``` not ```[2, 3, 1]```

Comment: You probably want `sorted(set(arr))` if you want a consistent ordering.

Comment: Sets are unordered. How would you determine which integer in the output corresponds to which integer in the input?

Comment: it was a typo but the result is [2,3,2]

Comment: @Chris, that would be pretty straightforward, just do unique_arr = set(arr)
occ = [arr.count(e) for e in unique_arr]
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([unique_arr,occ]).T and then you get which number yo uare counting

Comment: OP isn't using Pandas, and this isn't tagged for Pandas. Don't assume that libraries like that are installed, please.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that's the easiest and more clear way to see what you were asking. For those who don't have pandas installed, just write pip install pandas on your terminal.